# Rails/Docker - How to use credentials.yml.erc to protect sensitive from going to docker-compose.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to dockerize my existing rails application. I have been using credentials.yml for quite some time. My credentials.yml file looks something like this:

```
production:
 db_host: 'localhost'
 db_name: 'prod_db'
 db_username: 'username'
 db_password: 'password'

development:
 db_host: 'localhost'
 db_name: 'dev_db'
 db_username: 'username'
 db_password: 'password'

test:
 db_host: 'localhost'
 db_name: 'test_db'
 db_username: 'username'
 db_password: 'password'

secret_key_base: my_secret_key_base
```

And my database.yml file looks likes this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:db_name] %>
  username: <%= Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:db_username] %>
  password: <%= Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:db_password] %>
  host: <%= Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:db_host] %>
  template: template0

test:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:db_name] %>
  username: <%= Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:db_username] %>
  password: <%= Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:db_password] %>
  host: <%= Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:db_host] %>
  template: template0

production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:db_name] %>
  username: <%= Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:db_username] %>
  password: <%= Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:db_password] %>
  host: <%= Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:db_host] %>
  template: template0
```

Now I am not using docker swarm so I won't be able to use docker secrets. As postgres image requires environment variables to be set up, how do i provide the credentials without embedding them in my docker-compose file?

Here's the sample for my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
volumes:
  postgres_data: {}
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/app/Dockerfile
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - .:/my_app
  db:
    image: postgres:10.3
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` to [setup the database connection](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database) instead of messing with the credentials file.

For example:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://localhost/foo?username=bar&password=baz rails s
```

The values in `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` are merged with the values in `database.yml` so you can simply set some useful defaults there:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  template: template0

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test
```

You can set the env var for development in [the container config](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#substitute-environment-variables-in-compose-files). And the production credentials directly on the server or if you are using a SAAS service like heroku through the app config.

Comment: I think docker provides the username and password as env vars already. https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/postgres/#postgres_password